# How to redirect page when array value matched with database value

Tags: php, sql, database

```
if (isset($_POST['finalSeats']))
{
```

**getting variable from post**

```
$TicketType =$_POST['Tickettype'];
$seatS=$_POST['finalSeats'];
$EventId=$_POST["Eventid"];
```

**array getting from last page**

```
$cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
$sqlData = array();
```

**getting values one by one with foreach**

```
foreach($cats as $key => $cat ) {
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fistevent WHERE `Event_Id`=? AND `TicketType`=? AND `seats`= ?") or die($con->error);
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$EventId , $TicketType,$cat);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

**Bind the results**

```
$stmt-> bind_result($id,$Event_Id,$TicketType,$row_name,$seats,$Status);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$data[] = array($id,$Event_Id,$TicketType,$row_name,$seats,$Status);
$Tickettype=$TicketType;
$Rowname=$row_name;
$Seats=$seats;
$status=$Status;
```

**Comparing values array and database values**

```
if($Seats===$cat && $status==='Hold')
{
echo'<script>window.location="selection.php";</script>';
}
```

**if not matched update the query**

```
else
{
$seatS=$_POST['finalSeats'];
$Eventid=$_POST["Eventid"];
$_SESSION['Eventid']=$Eventid;
$cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`="Hold" where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`= ? ') or die($con->error);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['Eventid'], $cat);
foreach($cats as $key => $cat ) {
$stmt->execute();
} 
}

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated code snippets, you need to change couple of things in your code, such as:

- Change your prepared statement in the following way,

  ```
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fistevent WHERE `Event_Id`=? AND `TicketType`=? AND `seats`= ? AND status='Hold'") or die($con->error);
  ```

  This way, you don't have to use this `if($Seats===$cat && $status==='Hold')` conditional or `while($stmt->fetch()){ ...` statements in your code.
- And after binding the result, simply do this:

  ```
  ...
  $stmt->bind_result($id,$Event_Id,$TicketType,$row_name,$seats,$Status);
  if($stmt->num_rows){
      header("Location: selection.php");
      exit();
  }else{
      $seatS=$_POST['finalSeats'];
      $Eventid=$_POST["Eventid"];
      $_SESSION['Eventid']=$Eventid;
      $cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
      $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`="Hold" where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`= ? ') or die($con->error);
      foreach($cats as $cat ) {
          $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Eventid, $cat);
          $stmt->execute();
      } 
  }
  ```

### Solution:

As per the below conversation, the requirement was: if array( E4, E5 ,E6) already exists in database and their status is hold, and in the next turn someone selects (E3, E5, E7) (E5 being in the database and the corresponding status being hold), the page should get redirected and no value from (E3, E5, E7) array will get updated. The table will be updated only if array values are new and not on hold. So here's the solution code snippet,

```
if (isset($_POST['finalSeats'])) {
    $TicketType =$_POST['Tickettype'];
    $seatS=$_POST['finalSeats'];
    $EventId=$_POST["Eventid"];

    $cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fistevent WHERE `Event_Id`=? AND `TicketType`=? AND `seats`= ? AND status='Hold'") or die($con->error);
    $recordExists = false;
    foreach($cats as $cat ) {
        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$EventId , $TicketType,$cat);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows){
            $recordExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($recordExists){
        header("Location: selection.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        foreach($cats as $cat ) {
            $_SESSION['Eventid']=$Eventid;
            $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`="Hold" where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`= ? ') or die($con->error);
            foreach($cats as $cat ) {
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Eventid, $cat);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rahul I've updated my answer, please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: sir the answer provide by RïshïKêsh Kümar is quite ok.but there is a small issue that the loop not going in if part.it goes to else part only.if you help in it you can update your answer

Comment: @rahul That's the whole point, there's no point using `while()` loop in your code. Have you integrated the code snippets(given in **Update(1)** section) in your application? Is there anything *not working* now?

Comment: sir  your code is not working it is also not updating the records .but second answer updating the records and also check if array values matched with database values or not.. on this code only one problem that after updating the records it redirect the page as we do in if condition. otherwise it is working fine..

Comment: @rahul The `else` block won't redirect the user unless you have explicitly mentioned `header(...);exit();` in the `else` part. Having said this, I've updated the `else` part in my answer as well. Please test your application with the updated code snippets.

Comment: where we checked the array value matched with database values or not.because after that we can redirect the page

Comment: sir if array's any values matched with database value it should be redirect to last page ..if not matching any values with database update query will be run

Comment: @rahul You definitely didn't go through the answer properly,did you? *where we checked the array value matched with database values or not*, as I said in my answer you don't need this comparison at all, simply change your prepared statement and subsequent `if-else` block as given in the answer.

Comment: sir i had changed my code as you said .but it going in else part .first i select group of array E4, E5 ,E6  and after that table updated ..and the same time i am clicking same array except one value E3,E4,E5,E6 this time it is also updating the table in else part..so i 'think there is a small mistake in a code sir

Comment: @rahul So based on your statement, what's your expected behavior here?

Comment: if array( E4, E5 ,E6)one of them are already exists in database and the status is hold. then if someone again select the same value then it should print a message or redirect the page to last page.

Comment: @rahul What if array( E4, E5 ,E6) already exists in database and the status is hold, and in the next turn someone selects (E3, E5, E7) *(E5 being in the database and the corresponding status being hold)*, then what would be the expected behavior here?

Comment: sir ,The page should be redirect and don't update  (E3, E5, E7) any of them.. table will be updated only if array values are new and not on hold.

Comment: @rahul I think I understood your issue. Please try this solution, [https://pastebin.com/Lm39qspr](https://pastebin.com/Lm39qspr). If it resolves your issue then I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: You have done it sir.Thanks a lot for your effort ;)

Comment: @rahul You're welcome! I'm going to update my answer in a moment. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Sure sir.blessed :)

Comment: @rahul I've updated my answer and added the required explanation and code snippet. Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer to close the question, otherwise this question will floating around SO as *open* question.